# $PATH is different when I run bash from java processbuilder

Tags: java, bash

When I run a bach script containing "echo $Path" command what it outputs when run by java is different from what it outputs when run from command line. It also affects other commands of my script. Why is this happening and how do I avoid?

Following is my function to run a bashscript

```
public static String executeCommands(File tempScript, Boolean deleteFile)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    try {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("bash", tempScript.toString());
        pb.inheritIO();
        Process process = pb.start();
        process.waitFor();


        BufferedReader reader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }
        return line;

    } finally {
        if (deleteFile == true)
            tempScript.delete();
    }
}
```

when the script contains "echo $PATH" in bashscript

output is

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

But when I run from commandline output is

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/scala/scala-2.11.8/bin:/Users/<user>/Installations/activator-dist-1.3.10
```

Comment: Call `bash` with `-l`.

Comment: That is they way they are supposed to work. It is to be expected. Also stop running as root, it is a bad habit to fall into.

Comment: I was running this test from a unit test and I ran the unit test from eclipse. Why do you think it was running under root?

Comment: The paths of `/usr/sbin` and `/sbin` mean *secure* binaries. Those should be limited to elevated users, by default only root. You have those in your path.

Answer (score 2):

When we run the command from terminal it reads the environment variables from `.bashrc` file, but it seems eclipse does not read environment variables from `.bashrc`.

launch eclipse with `./eclipse -DPATH=$PATH` to read from `bashrc`

`PATH` variable from

1.terminal

```
user@ubuntu:~$ javac SS47.java 
user@ubuntu:~$ java SS47 
/home/user/perl5/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/user/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin:/home/user/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin:/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_60/bin:/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/bin:/home/user/dsc-cassandra-2.1.6/bin:/home/user/hadoop-2.6.0/bin:/home/user/hadoop-2.6.0/sbin:/home/user/android/android-studio/bin:/home/user/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:/home/user/elasticsearch-2.3.5/bin:/home/user/scala-2.11.8/bin::/home/user/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin
```

2.eclipse with out `$PATH`

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

3.eclipse with PATH `./eclipse -DPATH=$PATH`

```
/home/user/perl5/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/user/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin:/home/user/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin:/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_60/bin:/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/bin:/home/user/dsc-cassandra-2.1.6/bin:/home/user/hadoop-2.6.0/bin:/home/user/hadoop-2.6.0/sbin:/home/user/android/android-studio/bin:/home/user/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:/home/user/elasticsearch-2.3.5/bin:/home/user/scala-2.11.8/bin::/home/user/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin
```

Comment: I normally run eclipse from applications folder in mac. Is there any config I can change inside eclipse for it to read from bashrc also?

Comment: try launching from terminal `./eclipse -DPATH=$PATH` am using `Ubuntu`

Comment: or check if you have `/etc/environment` file, eclipse reads envs form this file during initialization, append `$PATH`  in environment file, restart eclipse

Comment: or you can add VM arguments in eclipse.ini file

Answer (score -1):

As [Elliott-Frisch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2970947/elliott-frisch) pointed out in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40168112/path-is-different-when-i-run-bash-from-java-processbuilder#comment67604406_40168112), just call `bash` with the option `-l` which

> Make[s] bash act as if it had been invoked as a login shell (see INVOCATION below). [Source](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

This way you don't have to call Eclipse with different launch options etc. and it makes your solution independent, being able to be run without the non customized Eclipse or just bare-bone JRE.

So just edit your call `ProcessBuilder` like this:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-l", tempScript.toString());
```